# fish shell can not tab complete

Tags: command-line, fish

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and I have installed the fish shell recently from http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/ ,  and i am quite fond of it. But the downside of using it is, it gives me below sigsegv error when i try to use the tab-completion feature :

```
fish: Process 17820, “fish_pager” from job 1, “fish_pager -c 3 -r 4  -p ''” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

How can i prevent this from happening?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a known issue with `fish` for a while, but there is actually a fix now [at its Github site](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/278). The developer commented when discussing the issue that

> Actually I think it's something else - we just didn't set the parent group ID in posix_spawn.

He has committed the fix now, but I think you will have to build it from source until that fix is incorporated in the beta builds at [the official site](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/beta.html). The instructions to build from source are straightforward and are on the beta page: (install `git` and `build-essential` if you don't have them already). There are no extra dependencies to install.

First, run

```
git clone git://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell.git
```

Then `cd` to the `fish-shell` folder and run:

```
autoconf
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You can use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` if you wish.

I just tried this method and it all worked fine- it took less than 3 minutes altogether.

Note: some good extensive documentation on `fish` is [available here](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/).